# Conditionally skip a Junit 5 test

Tags: junit

In my Junit Jupiter API 5.5 test, I am calling my method which internally makes a HTTP call to a remote service.
Now the remote service can be down or behave incorrectly. I want to skip my test in case the remote service is not behaving expectedly.

```
@Test
void testMe() {
  // do something
  Result res1 = myObject.retrieveResults(params)
  // assert something

  Result res2 = myObject.retrieveResults(param2)
  //asert on results
}

Result retrieveResults(Parameters param) {
 // do something
  // call to remote service
  // if they do not give result throw CustomException()
  // return Result
}
```

So basically in my test i would want to check if `myObject.retrieveResult` is throwing CustomException then skip that test, otherwise evaluate normally.

Comment: Why don't you just mock the remote service?

Comment: @ligi i still want to catch those issues through alerting, but do not want to prevent our builds just because remote service is down.

Comment: Sounds wrong to me tbh. testing should be separate from monitoring

Answer (score 14):

We have 2 different ways to accomplish this tasks in JUnit 5.

For demo purposes, I have created a basic class which sends a request to the url 
that is passed as an argument to its `call(String url)` method and 
returns `true` or `false` depending on the request result. 
The body of the method is irrelevant here.

### Using `Assumptions.assumeTrue()/assumeFalse()` methods

`Assumptions` class provides us with two overloaded methods - `assumeTrue` 
and `assumeFalse`. The idea is that, if the assumption is wrong, the test will be skipped.

So, the test will be something like this.

```java
@Test
void call1() {
    Assumptions.assumeTrue(new EndpointChecker(), "Endpoint is not available");
    Assertions.assertTrue(HttpCaller.call("https://www.google.com"));
}
```

Here is the code for `EndpointChecker` class.

```java
static class EndpointChecker implements BooleanSupplier {
    @Override
    public boolean getAsBoolean() {
        // check the endpoint here and return either true or false
        return false;
    }
}
```

When the test is run, the availability of the endpoint will be checked first, if it is up, then the test will run.

### Using JUnit 5 extension mechanisms.

So, let's start with creating the annotation. It is pretty straightforward.

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ExtendWith(EndpointAvailabilityCondition.class)
public @interface SkipWhenEndpointUnavailable {

    String uri();

}
```

And `EndpointAvailabilityCondition` class. Even though, it looks big, overall logic is very simple.

```java
import static org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation;

public class EndpointAvailabilityCondition implements ExecutionCondition {

    @Override
    public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(ExtensionContext context) {
        final var optional = findAnnotation(context.getElement(), SkipWhenEndpointUnavailable.class);
        if (optional.isPresent()) {
            final SkipWhenEndpointUnavailable annotation = optional.get();
            final String uri = annotation.uri();
            // check connection here start
            boolean result = false; // dummy value
            // check connection here end
            if (result) {
                return ConditionEvaluationResult.enabled("Connection is up");
            } else {
                return ConditionEvaluationResult.disabled("Connection is down");
            }
        }
        return ConditionEvaluationResult.enabled("No assumptions, moving on...");
    }

}
```

Hence, we can do the following in our tests.

```java
@Test
@SkipWhenEndpointUnavailable(uri = "https://www.google.com")
void call2() {
    Assertions.assertTrue(HttpCaller.call("https://www.google.com"));
}
```

We can go ahead and add `@Test` annotation over `@SkipWhenEndpointUnavailable` and remove it from our test code. Like, so:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ExtendWith(EndpointAvailabilityCondition.class)
@Test
public @interface SkipWhenEndpointUnavailable {

    String uri();

}
class HttpCallerTest {
    @SkipWhenEndpointUnavailable(uri = "https://www.google.com")
    void call2() {
        Assertions.assertTrue(HttpCaller.call("https://www.google.com"));
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.