# How to stop/skip Parameterize test without throwing exception?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, paramterized

I want to try to stop the test when the `param == 3`. I found a way to achieve this by using `Disable()`. However, this approach uses `throw`. Is there any way I can do this without throwing exceptions?

The idea is,`@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`annotation will make sure all the tests run according to how many values I have, in this case, 3.  `getPdInit_Level1_SUCCESS`does not have a level 3 user but another test, example `getPdInit_Level3_SUCCESS` contain implementation until level 3. So I only want to run `getPdInit_Level1_SUCCESS` 2 times and  `getPdInit_Level3_SUCCESS` 3 times.

```
private static class Disable {
        
        private final Object[] arguments;
        
        private Disable(Object[] arguments) {
            this.arguments = arguments;
        }
        
        public static Disable when(Object... arguments) {
            return new Disable(arguments);
        }
        
        public Disable is(Object... values) {
            if (Arrays.equals(arguments, values))
                throw new TestAbortedException("Test aborted for arguments " + Arrays.toString(values));
            return this;
        }
        
    }
```

```
        @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 0)
        public int fInput;
        
        @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 1)
        public int fOutput;
        
        @Parameterized.Parameters
        public static Collection userLevel() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                    {1, 3},
                    {2, 2},
                    {3, 3},
            });
        }
```

```
        @Test
        public void getPdInit_Level1_SUCCESS() {
        
            Disable.when(fInput, fOutput)
                    .is(3, 3);
            
            //Real test here
}
```

When using `Assumptions.assumeTrue()`, this is what I get :[image: Test Result]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally skip a Junit 5 test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60689337/conditionally-skip-a-junit-5-test)

Comment: The result is the same. ```Assumptions.assumeTrue()/assumeFalse()``` is the simplified version of my code and output the exception ```org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException: Assumption failed: assumption is not true```

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering with your solution or `Assumptions.assumeTrue()`?

Comment: My solution and ```Assumptions.assumeTrue()``` will throw exception which will resulting in ```Test failed```. I only want to skip the test.

Comment: @anggor `Assumptions.assumeTrue()`'s exception will be handled specially by the junit framework and mark the test as skipped, not failed.

Comment: @knittl I beg to differ. Please to updated question. I uploaded the result when I'm using ```Assumptions.assumeTrue()```

Comment: @anggor [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @anggorif you look closely, you see that you are not using `Assumptions` from JUnit 5 (`org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions`), but from `org.opentest4j`. Fix your imports, use the correct classes. (Sorry for only noticing now, I should have noticed that from your second comment already: it contains the wrong package name)